# How iOS prevent app from stealing files saved in google drive?

Tags: ios, security, cloud

Apple's Files app treats google drive as a folder and operates files saved in google drive in the same ways as local files saved on the phone. See ["Use the Files app on your iPhone, iPad, and iPod touch"](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT206481).

It is convenient, e.g., if want to send a file saved in google drive to a friend via iMessage, just browse into the google drive, select file and send. I sent files via another applications also.

Now the question comes: **what if an app on the phone wants to steal files saved in my google drive**?

I think this concern is common, as I trust google drive before because it has two-steps verification, I save some personal files in google drive. But now if I install google drive on my iphone, together with some other social communicators, it looks like the files in google drive can be easily get accessed by them. I don't feel safe anymore. There is [a lot of discussion](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/kFdlLMHKfQA).

**How does iOS prevent bad app from stealing files saved in google drive, or DropBox?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apps cannot simply access Google Drive. They must do so through a [`UIDocumentPickerViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentpickerviewcontroller) which requires user interaction

Comment: So each application is still in its own sandbox, no one can get an access to the whole file system, right? @Paulw11

Comment: That is correct. That is the central concept in iOS app security.